# Selectively importing data in sql

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

First, I apologize if the title is misleading. I am still quite new to this and not all that adept with the verbage in SQL.

I have a table named Original. It has 90 columns. I am seeking to create another table which takes 25 of these columns. Only one of them has a condition on it. The z column has values between 1 and 6. I want to copy/take those records where z is not equal to 2. As of yet, this is what i am thinking might work.

```
select 1-24,'z' not equal to 2 from dbo.original
```

Is it really this simple or is there more to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one out and see if it works out for you:

```
SELECT 1,2,3,...,23,24,z
FROM dbo.original
WHERE z != 2;
```

For any further clarifications don't hesitate to ask me!

Ted.